# mysql two dimensional array query result send as a mail

Tags: php, mysql, email, multidimensional-array, foreach

I need to send a mail using php mail function. Need the **count** of the BREAKFAST,LUNCH,EVENING,DINNER,MIDNIGHT **for each day** (from today to coming next 7 days) where each field is marked as "1".

Mysql table and the data

[image]

Need the **count** of the BREAKFAST,LUNCH,EVENING,DINNER,MIDNIGHT **for each day** (from today to coming next 7 days) where each field is marked as "1".

The most simple query to be looped :-

**select count(BREAKFAST) from foodPlan where BREAKFAST=1 and date="2014-09-17";**

[image]

In this way, row wise from today to the consecutive 7 days
Column - BREAKFAST,LUNCH,EVENING,DINNER,MIDNIGHT -each should provide the count which is marked as "1" needs t be counted.

The result needs to be mailed with these data in it:-

```
        $link =mysql_connect("172.17.xx.xxx", "username", "password") 
                              or die(mysql_error());
        //To select the database
        mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());

        //To get the current date 
        $date=date("Y-m-d");

        $dates = array();

        $dates[0] = $today;

        for ($i=1; $i<7; $i++) {
          $dates[$i] =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$i day"));
        }
         .....
         .....

        # This will set the Subject for the  Mail
        $subject = "FOODIE plan";


        $recipient = 'xx@yyyy.com';

        # The following details will be updated in the Body part of the mail
        $message = "Foodie";

        ....
        ....
        mail ( $recipient, $subject, $message, $header );
```

### **The data should look like this in the mail as below :-**

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what you have did yet?

Comment: please see the edits @Alankar

Comment: Can you show the array which you are getting?

Comment: Need to print the result of the mysql query in a report format.

Comment: Please check the last image. that is the desired outcome

Comment: The issue, is, the query should be run dynamically in a loop to get the total count of each column

Comment: This looks like poor design

Comment: The code which you posted will never output something like you want. Go try to make it first, and come back when you have any errors.

Answer (score 0):

**SUM** combined with **GROUP BY** provide the functions you want in SQL.

So, you should be able to use something like:

```
SELECT
    date,
    SUM(BREAKFAST) as breakfast_total,
    SUM(LUNCH) as lunch_total
FROM foodPlan
WHERE date >= $firstday AND date <= $lastday
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
// Table columns are putted in the array.
$columnNames = array('BREAKFAST','LUNCH','EVENING','DINNER','MIDNIGHT');
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$dates = array();

$dates[0] = $today;

for ($i=1; $i<7; $i++) {
  $dates[$i] =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$i day"));
}

$result = array();
foreach ($columnNames as $column) {
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        $query = "SELECT count(".$column.") as cnt FROM foodplan WHERE " .$column. "= 1 AND date = '".$date."'";
        $res = mysql_query($query);
        $row = mysql_num_rows($res);
        if ($row > 0) {
            $record = mysql_fetch_assoc($record);
            $result[$date][$column] = $record['cnt'];   
        } else {
            // if we don't found any record in the case.
            $result[$date][$column] = 0;    
        }
    }
}

// creating table to send in email body 
$emailMessage = "<table>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>";
                    foreach ($columnNames as $cKey => $cValue) { 
                            $emailMessage .= "<th>".$cValue."</th>";
                    }
$emailMessage .= "</tr>";
                    foreach ($result as $rDate => $rDataValue) { 
                        $emailMessage .= "<tr><td>".$rDate."</td>";
                            foreach ($columnNames as $col) { 
                                $emailMessage .= "<td>".$rDataValue[$col]."</td>";
                            }   
                        $emailMessage .= "</tr>";
                    } 
$emailMessage .= "</table>";
```

This will have to show the table as you want.